# Property "style" does not exist or is read-only

Tags: java, javafx

I'm having a problem with the choicebox in JavaFX8. Once I am using above below code it's working fine getting dropdown list.

```
<ChoiceBox fx:id="messageChoiceBox" maxWidth="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="24.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <items>
        <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
            <String fx:value="Inbox" style="-fx-background-image: url('file:resources/images/message/draft.png');" />
            <String fx:value="Facebook" />
            <String fx:value="Orkut" />
            <String fx:value="LinkedIn" />
            <String fx:value="Google Plus" />
        </FXCollections>
    </items>
    <HBox.margin>
        <Insets right="40.0" top="3.0" />
    </HBox.margin>
</ChoiceBox>
```

But my problem is, i needed to use image also for each fx:value

```
<String fx:value="Facebook" style="-fx-background-image: url('myPath/facebook.png');" />
<String fx:value="Orkut" style="-fx-background-image: url('myPath/Orkut.png');" />
<String fx:value="LinkedIn" style="-fx-background-image: url('myPath/LinkedIn.png');" />
<String fx:value="Google Plus" style="-fx-background-image: url('myPath/Google Plus.png');" />
```

once I run this getting error..

```
Caused by: com.sun.javafx.fxml.PropertyNotFoundException: Property "style" does not exist or is read-only. 
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processValue(Unknown Source) 
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processPropertyAttribute(Unknown Source)...
```

Does anyone knows how to fix this issue? And let me know 
Is there any way to add style in choice box in FXML.

Many Thank you to All..

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to do: your FXML code is equivalent to `String item = "Inbox" ; ` and then `item.setStyle("...");`. Clearly, `String` does not define a `setStyle` method. If you want to style cells, you should use a [`ComboBox`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html) with a [`cellFactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html#cellFactoryProperty) (which you would need to define in the controller).

Comment: Many thank you James.......

Answer (score 1):

Since `java.lang.String` doesn't offer a style property, you have to use your own class that contains value and style.

Note that `ChoiceBox` doesn't support styling items, therefore I recommend using a [`ComboBox`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html) with a custom cell factory instead:

#### Class for styled String

```
public class StyledString {

    private final String value;
    private final String style;

    // allows creating instances from fxml with given value and style
    public StyledString(@NamedArg("value") String value, @NamedArg("style") String style) {
        this.value = value;
        this.style = style;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public String getStyle() {
        return style;
    }

}
```

#### CellFactory

```
public class StyledListCellsFactory implements Callback<ListView<StyledString>, ListCell<StyledString>> {

    @Override
    public ListCell<StyledString> call(ListView<StyledString> param) {
        return new ListCell<StyledString>() {

            @Override
            protected void updateItem(StyledString item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);

                if (item == null || empty) {
                    setText(null);
                    setStyle(null);
                } else {
                    setText(item.getValue());
                    setStyle(item.getStyle());
                }
            }

        };
    }

}
```

#### fxml

Make sure the relevant classes are imported (`StyledString` and `StyledListCellsFactory`)

```
<ComboBox fx:id="messageChoiceBox" maxWidth="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="24.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <cellFactory>
        <StyledListCellsFactory/>
    </cellFactory>
    <items>
        <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
            <StyledString value="Inbox" style="-fx-background-image: url('file:resources/images/ib.png');" />
            <StyledString value="Facebook" style="-fx-background-image: url('file:resources/images/fb.png');" />
            <StyledString value="Orkut" style="-fx-background-image: url('file:resources/images/index.jpg');" />
            <StyledString value="LinkedIn" />
            <StyledString value="Google Plus" />
        </FXCollections>
    </items>
    <HBox.margin>
        <Insets right="40.0" top="3.0" />
    </HBox.margin>
</ComboBox>
```

However if it's always a image you use, consider using the image url instead of style. you could still construct the style string using the url and you could also use the cell factory to display the image as [`graphic`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#graphicProperty) (see [ComboBox javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html) for an example use of the `graphic` property (the rectangle can be replaced with an `ImageView` and set the `contentDisplay` property to something else))